# Printing Dynamic Array, Visual Studio - c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I wrote a simple code in C to practice dynamic arrays, but visual studio wont run it properly? It shows no errors and seems to store the inputs, but doesn't print. Please helppp.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 3

int main(void){

    int *a = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));
    int i;

    if (a == NULL){
        puts("not enough memory");
    }
    else{
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            printf("entry %d\n", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        printf("printing\n");
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        }
            free(a);

        puts("press any key to exit...");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks okay and runs for me, including printing out the entered values at the end.  Are you sure this is the correct code?  If it is, which version of Visual Studio are you using and how do you compile it?

Comment: I'm using VS 2013 pro. I use the local windows debugger. After I enter the last value the program closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

newline that has not been consumed in the **scanf** (at last) is consumed in the last **getchar**. It does not become the stopped state so, as you thought.

So for example as follows.

change

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c", &a[i]);//consumed newline every time
```

or

change

```
getchar();
```

to

```
getchar();//consumed last newline for scanf
getchar();//wait for key stroke
```